# vscode: evaluating multiple selected lines in the debug console causes an indentation error (with python classes)

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have some working code like so in VSCode:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def run(self):
        a = 3
        b = 4
        c = a + b
MyClass().run()
```

If I set a breakpoint at line `a = 3`, which is then reached during debugging, and I then select lines `a = 3` up to and including `c = a + b` and want to have all 3 lines evaluated in the debug console, this results in the lines being copied to the debug console as follows:

```
a = 3
        b = 4
        c = a + b
```

Which causes the following error because the indentation is wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lukas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 419, in evaluate_expression
    compiled = compile(_expression_to_evaluate(expression), '<string>', 'eval')
  File "<string>", line 1
    a = 3
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lukas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 1207, in internal_evaluate_expression_json
    pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(py_db, frame, expression, is_exec=True)
  File "/home/lukas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 371, in new_func
    return _run_with_unblock_threads(original_func, py_db, curr_thread, frame, expression, is_exec)
  File "/home/lukas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 339, in _run_with_unblock_threads
    return _run_with_interrupt_thread(original_func, py_db, curr_thread, frame, expression, is_exec)
  File "/home/lukas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 310, in _run_with_interrupt_thread
    return original_func(py_db, frame, expression, is_exec)
  File "/home/lukas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 421, in evaluate_expression
    Exec(_expression_to_evaluate(expression), updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
  File "/home/lukas/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1230869389/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 2
    b = 4
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

In VSCode, how can I copy multiple lines with only as much indentation as the first line, so that the pasted code is properly indented?

Answer (score 0):

You really have copied the indent from the second line.

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> when you copy from `a` to `a+b` to avoid this.